# windows application terminated when install in c drive, But it work for D drive

Tags: c#, winforms, file-watcher

I have developed a windows form application which is run in system tray. In application, I used Filewatcher to detect newly downloaded file and send each file to the local printer using acrobat reader.exe.
When this application installed in C drive, the application does not work properly. but when it install in D drive It works.
I have no idea about what is the reason. I have handled log error for exceptions. there aren't any error in log also.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do your application has permission to read/write into C drive? Try running it as administrator.

Comment: Almost always in this sort of situation, in my experience, lack of logging of errors is not indicative of an absence of errors but rather that somewhere within the code, something is *swallowing* errors (often with an empty `catch` block). But with no code to look at, it's just a guessing game here.

Comment: The application running user is not an admin, But my download directory in D drive. user have full permission for D drive. I think read/write permission effect for this.?